# Session and Cookies asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I was reading an article on asp.net session vs viewstate and after reading the article I got a doubt i.e. the article says if I create a session variable i.e.
Session("username")="username" this value is saved on webserver and webserver on start of first request creates a cookie and store it on a client machine and then retrieve the session variables for specific user based on the cookie value stored on client machine.

My doubts are - How and where does the session variables are stored on the server.

My understanding is based on the sessionID i.e. cookie value stored on client machine the webserver created a folder and for all the session variables created it create file and store the data i.e.  For all the session variables stored on webserver there will be only one cookie stored on client machine- Please correct me if I am wrong in understanding to what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.Net allows you to configure where you want your sessions variables stored. The documentation on the different options you can use is available here:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

The short version is that session variables *are* stored in memory with your application by default, but you can also use a separate process or even Sql Server. None of the options uses a folder on your disk, though. That would be slow. If you really want to use a folder on the server, you have to write your own custom provider.

Comment: Thanks Joel for the quick  response and it  has answered my question. would appreciate if you could comment on the statement I made i.e.  (For all the session variables stored on webserver there will be only one cookie stored on client machine i.e.  in the form of sessionId).

Comment: That is correct in essence, but it's a bit more complicated than that in practice. The token stored in the cookie alone is not enough to gain access to a session. That would be a security flaw, as cookies are easy to intercept or hijack. The server can perform additional validation on the token... for example, matching it to a remote IP/port, user agent, host, etc

Comment: The reason why I got this conclusion is - As when cookies are disabled on client browser only the token is send through the site url, not sure if the remote IP/Port is send through http request header as programmatically I have never implemented this, Is this inbuilt feature in asp.net?